# Replace all duplicates in an array

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class ClassNameHere {
public static void main(String[] args) {
  

  String[] items = new String[]{"John","Bob","David", "Carrie", "John","Bob","Dawson"};
 
  String [] clone = new String[items.length];
  
   for (int i =0; i<items.length; i++) {
        clone[i] = items[i]; // copying the items array to clone
    }
  
   for (int i=items.length-1; i>=0; i--) { //trying to find duplicates.
        for (int j = i-1; j>=0; j--) {
            if (items[i].equals(items[j])) {
            
    }
  
 
  
 }
}
```

Hi, I am currently working on my array to remove all duplicate and change it to null value and move all null value to right side. So for example, since there are "John" and "Bob" duplicate exists, this is what I expect to make: *{"David", "Carrie", "John","Bob","Dawson",null,null}*.

Also, you will see I am making a clone array of items because I do not want to change any value of original items.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope this code help you :)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

     String[] items = new String[]{"John","Bob","David", "Carrie", "John","Bob","Dawson"};

    String [] clone = new String[items.length];

    for (int i =0; i<items.length; i++) {
        clone[i] = items[i]; // copying the items array to clone
    }

    for (int i=items.length-1; i>=0; i--) { //trying to find duplicates.
        for (int j = i-1; j>=0; j--) {
            if (items[i].equals(items[j])) {
                items[i]=null;
                break;
            }
        }
        
    }
    
    int countOfNulls=0;
    for (int i=0 ; i<items.length;i++) {

        if(items[i]==null){
             countOfNulls++;
        }
    }

    for (int c=0 ;c<countOfNulls;c++) {

        for (int i=0 ; i<items.length;i++) { 

            if(items[i]==null){

                for(int j=i+1;j<items.length;j++){

                    items[j-1]=items[j];

                }

             items[items.length-1]=null;

            }

        }
    }

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(items));
}
```

Comment: @YangHeuin I edit the comment.. see that now.

Comment: The complexity of this code is much higher since it's using 3 nested for loops.

Comment: @RukshanJayasekara Yeah, I know, but the question did not say whether complexity is important to them or not. I assumed this was just a simple exercise :) because he didn't want to use an import statement.

Comment: @NiloofarAdelkhani Yeah yeah I get it :)

Answer (score 8):

Try this.

```
String[] items = new String[] {"John", "Bob", "David", "Carrie", "John", "Bob", "Dawson"};
String[] clone = Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.stream(items)
    .distinct().toArray(String[]::new), items.length);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(clone));
```

output:

```
[John, Bob, David, Carrie, Dawson, null, null]
```

If you don't want to use `Stream`

```
String[] items = new String[] {"John", "Bob", null, "David", "Carrie", "John", "Bob", "Dawson"};
int length = items.length;
String[] clone = new String[length];
L: for (int i = 0, last = 0; i < length; ++i) {
    String item = items[i];
    if (item == null) continue;
    for (int j = 0; j < last; ++j)
        if (item.equals(clone[j]))
            continue L;
    clone[last++] = items[i];
}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(clone));
```

output:

```
[John, Bob, David, Carrie, Dawson, null, null, null]
```

Comment: @YangHeuin My code is only importing `java.util.Arrays`.

Comment: This should be the most suitable solution with the least complexity (using only util.arrays).

Answer (score 4):

### Solution using `HashSet`

Complexity - O(n)

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  

 String[] items = new String[]{"John","Bob","David", "Carrie", "John","Bob","Dawson"};
 
  String [] clone = new String[items.length];
  
   for (int i =0; i<items.length; i++) {
        clone[i] = items[i]; // copying the items array to clone
    }
  
  HashSet set = new HashSet();
    for (int i =0; i<items.length; i++) { 
        if (set.add(items[i]) == false) { 
        items[i] = null;
    } 
        
    }
    
   //shifting the "null"s to right side.

   String[] newArray = new String[items.length];
   int index = 0;
   for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    if (items[i] != null) {
        newArray[index++] = items[i];
    }
   }
   System.out.println(Arrays.toString(newArray)); //[John, Bob, David, Carrie, Dawson, null, null]


  }
```

Comment: I'll keep this answer as it is because some others can use it. There seems to be an answer using only arrays already, but I'll add another one.

Answer (score 4):

### A solution using only Arrays

Complexity - O(n^2)

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  

 String[] items = new String[]{"John","Bob","David", "Carrie", "John","Bob","Dawson"};
 
  String [] clone = new String[items.length];
  
   for (int i =0; i<items.length; i++) {
        clone[i] = items[i]; // copying the items array to clone
    }
  
   for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++) { 
      for (int j = i + 1 ; j < items.length; j++) { 
          if (items[i].equals(items[j])) {  
              items[j] = "null"; //here we can't use null as it throws NullPointerException.
          } 
      } 
  }
  
  for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    if (items[i].equals("null")) {
        items[i] = null;
    }
   }
    
   String[] newArray = new String[items.length];
   int index = 0;
   for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    if (items[i] != null) {
        newArray[index++] = items[i];
    }
   }
   System.out.println(Arrays.toString(newArray)); //[John, Bob, David, Carrie, Dawson, null, null]

  }
```

Comment: The reason is you can not use `String.equals(null)`. You have to use a String. In your use case if you need to check for input null values, then it's better to use `==`. I thought inputs should be strings, that's why I used `equals`

Answer (score 2):

You can create a 2nd array to store the elements you find at 1st array.

As long as you're walking in the 1st array, if the element you are inspecting is already present in the second array, add a null element, otherwise, copy the element into the second array.

After that, you need to exchange the null elements so they will be located in the end of the array. You can do that walking several times in the array and shifting the null value to the right, until you have no more null values on the left.